# PIL doesn't recognize jpeg library under Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

Scripts like that:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
img = Image.open('1.JPG')
thumb = ImageOps.fit(img, (200,200) , Image.ANTIALIAS, (0.5, 0.5))
```

cause this IOError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

How do I get jpeg support for my PIL? That issue seems to be well known but the existing threads don't solve it for me. I use brew and pip for my python packages and have already tried the following:

- `brew install jpeg` 
  causes `Error: jpeg-8d already installed`
- `brew install libjpeg` causes `Error: jpeg-8d already installed`
- `sudo pip install Pillow` - installation works but does not change anything

How do I get jpeg support for my PIL installation? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't understand why, but reinstalling PIL fixed the issue:

```
sudo pip uninstall pil
sudo pip install pil
```

Comment: Well, it seems that you installed the jpeg libraries after you installed PIL. The jpeg library is linked at the compilation time, that's why you had to reinstall PIL.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and solved it by symlinking the libraries PIL was looking for into `/usr/lib` (where it was actually looking for them):

```
# symlink image libraries so PIL can find them
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
# etc for any other libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

For non OSX people landing here, I found [linking](http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/) to the 64 bit libraries on my 64 bit Ubuntu system to fix the compile issue.